# How to Get Custom Slack App Channel ID via Slack API

Tags: salesforce, slack, slack-api, apex

I'm currently working with the Slack API and facing a specific challenge. I need to obtain the channel ID for a custom Slack app. To clarify, I'm not looking for the IDs of regular Slack channels, which I understand can be retrieved using the **conversations.list** method. Instead, I need to find the channel ID that is specific to a custom Slack app.

An example of the kind of Channel ID I'm seeking would look something like this: "D01ABCD02EF3".

Is there a way to obtain this specific type of channel ID using the Slack API? Please note that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve manually copying the ID from the Slack team URL.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`conversations.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open) would help: it does open or resumes a direct message or multi-person direct message.

```py
import slack_sdk

def get_custom_app_channel_id(token, app_user_id):
    client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=token)
    response = client.conversations_open(users=[app_user_id])
    return response['channel']['id']

# Replace 'your-token' and 'app-user-id' with your actual token and the app's user ID
channel_id = get_custom_app_channel_id('your-token', 'app-user-id')
print(f"Custom Slack App Channel ID: {channel_id}")
```

Replace `'your-token'` with your Slack auth token and `'app-user-id'` with the user ID of your custom Slack app. The user ID for a custom Slack app is typically found in your Slack app configuration under 'App Home'.
And make sure your Slack token has permissions for the `conversations.open` method.

That will open or resume a conversation with the app's user ID and return the ID of that direct message channel, which is what you would be looking for.

---

With [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list), that would be:

```py
import slack_sdk

def get_app_user_id(token, app_name):
    client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=token)
    response = client.users_list()
    for user in response['members']:
        if user.get('name') == app_name:
            return user.get('id')
    return None

def get_custom_app_channel_id(token, app_name):
    app_user_id = get_app_user_id(token, app_name)
    if app_user_id:
        client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=token)
        response = client.conversations_open(users=[app_user_id])
        return response['channel']['id']
    return None

# Replace with your actual Slack auth token and app name
channel_id = get_custom_app_channel_id('your-token', 'your-app-name')
print(f"Custom Slack App Channel ID: {channel_id}")
```

That would find the user ID of your custom Slack app, and then use it to open a conversation (DM channel) with the app, returning the channel ID.

Comment: Sounds good. Let me test and I'll come back with results

Comment: QQ: Is there method to get 'app-user-id' using slack api method? I dont want to use manual copy pasting

Comment: Answer: users.list

Comment: @Mamed Nice! I have edited the answer to include a possible function using `users.list`.

Comment: Sad news: {"ok":false,"error":"cannot_dm_bot"}

The test is working when I do it manually using https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open/test but not in code

Comment: @Mamed Does your bot token have the necessary permissions? It should have scopes to access both `users.list` and `conversations.open`.

Comment: Yep they do have all scopes (otherwise I will get error)

Answer (score 0):

What about [users.conversations](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations) method? You can pass

- *a user token* as 'token'
- *im* as 'types'
- *your app Member ID* as 'user'

and you will get the ID of the desired conversation.

Comment: There is no Channel Id of app